# loop to create dynamic variables

Tags: python

i have this code:

```
    if opt1 is not None:
        user_a, db_a = opt1.split("/") 
        db_a = country_assoc(int(db_a))
        client_a = Client(None, user_a, db_a)
        data_client_a = client_a.get_user() 

    if opt2 is not None:
        user_b, db_b = opt2.split("/")  
        db_b = country_assoc(int(db_b))
        client_b = Client(None, user_b, db_b)
        data_client_b = client_b.get_user() 

    ....
```

But, i want to generate a similar structure with a loop.

What is the correct way to do that? I am trying this

```
    abcde = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
    for idx, val in enumerate(abcde):
        if opt+idx is not None:
            user_+val, db_+val = opt+idx.split("/") 
            db_+val = country_assoc(int(db_+val))
            client_+val = Client(None, user_+val, db_+val)
            data_client_+val = client_+val.get_user()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = [opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4, opt5]

data_clients = []
   for j in a:
      if j is not None:
         user, db = j.split("/") 
         db = country_assoc(int(db))
         client = Client(None, user, db)
         data_clients.append(client.get_user())
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't understand why people feel the need to try and do this sort of thing. Variable names are not data. There is never a good reason to create variable names dynamically.

Simply put your values in a dictionary or a list.

```
for idx, val in enumerate(abcde):
    if opts[idx] is not None:
        user, db = opts[idx].split("/")
        users[val] = user
        dbs[val] = country_assoc(int(db))
        clients[val] = Client(None, user, db)
        data_clients.append(clients[val].get_user())
```